# constructor Bookings in class bookings cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

constructor Bookings in class bookings cannot be applied to given types. Any fixes chaps?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
  * Imports the Array List required for the application to use methods such as add, remove, size ect.
*/
public class Trip {

        private ArrayList<Bookings> Booking;
        public String Date;
        public String Trip;
        public String Code;
        public double price;
        public int booking_id;

        private int tripID;
        private String tripDestination;


        /**
          * Constructor 
          */
        public Trip(int ltripID,String ltripDestination, int ltripCapacity, double price)
        {
             Booking = new ArrayList<Bookings>();
             booking_id = 0;
             tripID = ltripID;
             tripDestination = ltripDestination;
             price = price;
        }

        public int BookingsSeats(String Code, int noAdults, int noChildren, String cForename, String cSurename, String cNumber)
        {
             Bookings newbooking;
             booking_id++;

             newbooking = new Bookings(Code, noAdults, noChildren, cForename, cSurename, cNumber, booking_id);

            return booking_id;
        }


        public void RemoveBooking(int ID)
        {
            //for (Booking obj : Bookings)
            //{
            //    if (obj.IDget() ==ID)
            //   {
            //       Bookings.remove(obj);
            //   }
         }
      }


     //public void ToString()
    // {
       //  System.out.printIn("");
        // System.out.printIn("This code " + code );
        // System.out.printIn("This date " + Date);
        // System.out.printIn("Trip Destination " + Destincation);
        // System.out.printIn("Price" + Price); 

        // for (Booking obj : Bookings )
       //  {
            // system.out.printIn(obj.ToString());
            // system.out.printIn("");
         //}
      //}
 //}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an ordinary compilation error which can be resolved by taking a minute to look at what types are being passed in to your method call and which are actually expected. This question has no value to future visitors.

Comment: What does the `Bookings` class look like (at least show us the constructors)?

Answer (score 0):

By saying this:

```
new Bookings(Code, noAdults, noChildren, cForename, cSurename, cNumber, booking_id);
```

you're expecting the following constructor signature to exist in your `Bookings` class:

```
Bookings(String, int, int, String, String, String, int)
```

Figure out which parameter index is mismatched to your constructor declaration.